# Finding uid from a hash not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a JSON response from Facebook liking like this.

```
[
 {"uid"=>123, "name"=>"Test", "is_app_user"=>true},
 {"uid"=>1234, "name"=>"Test1", "is_app_user"=>true}
]
```

I save this result to @test and then:

```
@test.select {|k,v| k == "name"}}
```

But the result is an empty array instead of the desired result:

```
[]
```

Desired output (1)

```
[{"name" => "Test"}, { "name" => "Test1"}]
```

and then (2)

```
[Test, Test1] * This will be used to query the database
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: 1: What does `@test.class` return? 2: Have you tried printing `k` and `v` inside your select block? If not, then do it, and that should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@test = [
  {"uid"=>123, "name"=>"Test", "is_app_user"=>true},
  {"uid"=>1234, "name"=>"Test1", "is_app_user"=>true}
]

@test.collect { |itm| itm["name"] }

=> ["Test", "Test1"]
```

Comment: `NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for #<Hash:0x00000004e25848>)` not working mate.

Comment: Thanks mate. Please edit your response a bit because in Rails it's printing the 1st respond if I print `@test` I had to save `@test.collect { |itm| itm["name"] }` in a new variable and print that variable instead of test. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to modify `@test` in-place, then use `collect!` instead of `collect`, that way you do not have to reassign. This works with many methods in ruby. Like `gsub` vs. `gsub!` for example.